# Where to get Microsoft.practices.composite.unityextension.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, unity-container, prism

Where to find  Microsoft.Practices.Composite.UnityExtensions.dll for Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll thats of version 2.1.505.2..

I was using 1.2.0.0 version of unity dll . While i changed the version to 2.1.505.2 the code gave me an error saying unityextension is depenedent to 1.2.0.0 version of unity dll ...

the version I am using is 2.0.0.0 of unityextension.
I really need help .. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps as documented in [official website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921128(v=pandp.20).aspx) :-

> 1.In Visual Studio, create a new Silverlight application. To do this, point to New on the File menu, and then click Project. In the Project
>   types list, click Silverlight in the Visual C# node. In the Templates
>   box, click Silverlight Application. Finally, set the project's name,
>   such as CALApplication1, specify a valid location, and then click OK.
>   This project will be the Shell project of your application.
>
> 2.On the Add Silverlight Application dialog box, make sure the Add a new ASP.NET Web project to the solution to host Silverlight option is
>   selected, and then click OK.
>
> 3.(Optional) In Windows Explorer, create a folder named Library inside your solution's folder, and then copy the following assemblies into
>   the folder
>
> ◦Microsoft.Practices.Composite.UnityExtensions.dll. This assembly
>   contains base and utility classes you can reuse in applications based
>   on the Composite Application Library for Silverlight that consume the
>   Unity Application Block. For example, it contains a bootstrapper base
>   class, the UnityBootstrapper class, that creates and configures a
>   Unity container with default services when the application starts.